# Do Mystic Talents level with Mystic level or total level?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, psionics

The [UA Mystic](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/Psionics_and_Mystic_V2.pdf) is basically 5e's psionicist. In addition to 'Disciplines' they get a number of 'Talents'. These look like the Mystic's cantrip-equivalents to me (Thought Spear is basically a lower-damage Eldritch Blast, Mind Thrust is basically a 5'-range Repelling Eldritch Blast with lower damage).

My question is: is there an official ruling on whether Talents level based on Mystic level or total level?

I notice the disciplines all specifically state 'Mystic level' while the talents just say 'level' so I assume it's intended to be total level (all classes).

Comment: Everything else that simply specifies level and not [specific class] level is treated as total level, so I don't see any reason why this would be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pretty sure it's total level**

As you stated yourself, there are some striking similarities between *Mystic Talents* and *Cantrips*. The most obvious being the power increases at levels 5, 11 and 17, and for Cantrips these levels refer to your character's total level.

The most convincing argument for this, however, is that levels **11** and **17** are being mentioned, whereas the Mystic's level progression table only goes to **10**.

I can't give you a quote of an official ruling, which you asked for, but this seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: It's probably important to note that, since UA articles are not official rules, that it will be impossible to get an official ruling until the Mystic is published in an official source.

Comment: Mind Thrust
Psionic Talent
As an action, you target one creature you can see 
within 120 feet of you. The target must succeed 
on an Intelligence saving throw or take 1d10 
psychic damage.
The talent’s damage increases by 1d10 when 
you reach 5th level (2d10), 11th level (3d10), 
and 17th level (4d10).